# How to redirect example.com to example.com/espanol on .NET Core 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-5.0

We are migrating an old site and want to maintain the same URL structure. We don't have an `index.cshtml`; instead we are using as our default page `english.cshtml`.

So, we have:

1. `example.com`
2. `example.com\english`
3. `example.com\espanol`

All three are being served by `english.cshtml`, by adding these routes options:

```cs
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
   options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/english", "espanol");
   options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/english", "");
});
```

What we want to do is redirect `example.com` to `example.com/espanol`.

We originally tried this on `english.cshtml`, but it didn't work.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
{
    var path = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.ToLower().Replace("/", "");
    if (path == string.Empty)
    {
       RedirectToPagePermanent("espanol");
    }
    return Page();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out

```
.AddRedirect("(^$)", "espanol", 301);
```